# CRATE db tables are causing an error when upgrading to CRATE:4.3.4 from CRATE:4.2.7

Tags: java, sql, elasticsearch, crate, cratedb

Facing the below error while restoring snapshots or upgrade cratedb to a higher version from 4.2.7 to 4.3.4

```
SnapshotRestoreException[[repo_name:snapshot_name/******] cannot restore index [schema_name.table_name] because it cannot be upgraded]
```

```
org.elasticsearch.snapshots.SnapshotRestoreException: [repo_name:snapshot_name/******] cannot restore index [schema_name.table_name] because it cannot be upgraded
    at org.elasticsearch.snapshots.RestoreService$1.execute(RestoreService.java:273)
    at org.elasticsearch.cluster.ClusterStateUpdateTask.execute(ClusterStateUpdateTask.java:45)
    at org.elasticsearch.cluster.service.MasterService.executeTasks(MasterService.java:681)
    at org.elasticsearch.cluster.service.MasterService.calculateTaskOutputs(MasterService.java:307)
    at org.elasticsearch.cluster.service.MasterService.runTasks(MasterService.java:207)
    at org.elasticsearch.cluster.service.MasterService$Batcher.run(MasterService.java:139)
    at org.elasticsearch.cluster.service.TaskBatcher.runIfNotProcessed(TaskBatcher.java:153)
    at org.elasticsearch.cluster.service.TaskBatcher$BatchedTask.run(TaskBatcher.java:191)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.PrioritizedEsThreadPoolExecutor$TieBreakingPrioritizedRunnable.runAndClean(PrioritizedEsThreadPoolExecutor.java:258)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.PrioritizedEsThreadPoolExecutor$TieBreakingPrioritizedRunnable.run(PrioritizedEsThreadPoolExecutor.java:221)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: unable to upgrade the mappings for the index [[repo_name:snapshot_name/******]]
    at org.elasticsearch.cluster.metadata.MetadataIndexUpgradeService.checkMappingsCompatibility(MetadataIndexUpgradeService.java:175)
    at org.elasticsearch.cluster.metadata.MetadataIndexUpgradeService.upgradeIndexMetadata(MetadataIndexUpgradeService.java:98)
    at org.elasticsearch.snapshots.RestoreService$1.execute(RestoreService.java:270)
    ... 12 more
Caused by: org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.MapperParsingException: Failed to parse mapping [default]: Mapping definition for [dynamicFieldName3] has unsupported parameters:  [fields : {keyword={type=keyword, ignore_above=256}}]
    at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.MapperService.internalMerge(MapperService.java:285)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.MapperService.internalMerge(MapperService.java:272)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.MapperService.merge(MapperService.java:251)
    at org.elasticsearch.cluster.metadata.MetadataIndexUpgradeService.checkMappingsCompatibility(MetadataIndexUpgradeService.java:171)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.MapperParsingException: Mapping definition for [dynamicFieldName3] has unsupported parameters:  [fields : {keyword={type=keyword, ignore_above=256}}]
    at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.DocumentMapperParser.checkNoRemainingFields(DocumentMapperParser.java:153)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.DocumentMapperParser.checkNoRemainingFields(DocumentMapperParser.java:147)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.ObjectMapper$TypeParser.parseProperties(ObjectMapper.java:215)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.ObjectMapper$TypeParser.parseObjectOrDocumentTypeProperties(ObjectMapper.java:163)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.ObjectMapper$TypeParser.parse(ObjectMapper.java:134)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.ObjectMapper$TypeParser.parseProperties(ObjectMapper.java:207)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.ObjectMapper$TypeParser.parseObjectOrDocumentTypeProperties(ObjectMapper.java:163)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.ObjectMapper$TypeParser.parse(ObjectMapper.java:134)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.ArrayTypeParser.parse(ArrayTypeParser.java:51)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.ObjectMapper$TypeParser.parseProperties(ObjectMapper.java:207)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.ObjectMapper$TypeParser.parseObjectOrDocumentTypeProperties(ObjectMapper.java:163)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.ObjectMapper$TypeParser.parse(ObjectMapper.java:134)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.ObjectMapper$TypeParser.parseProperties(ObjectMapper.java:207)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.ObjectMapper$TypeParser.parseObjectOrDocumentTypeProperties(ObjectMapper.java:163)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.RootObjectMapper$TypeParser.parse(RootObjectMapper.java:103)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.DocumentMapperParser.parse(DocumentMapperParser.java:101)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.DocumentMapperParser.parse(DocumentMapperParser.java:89)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.MapperService.internalMerge(MapperService.java:283)
```

Below is the sample table creation schema.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS TABLE_NAME (
  "id" STRING,
  "field1" STRING NOT NULL,
  "field2" STRING NOT NULL,
  "field3" OBJECT NOT NULL,
  "createdAt" TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
  "updatedAt" TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY ("field1", "field2")
)
```

As field3 is the dynamic object, it'll allow adding more attributes into it.

So, now after data is inserted into the table the current schema is as follows

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS TABLE_NAME (
  "id" STRING,
  "field1" STRING NOT NULL,
  "field2" STRING NOT NULL,
  "field3" OBJECT(DYNAMIC) AS (
      "dynamicField1" BOOLEAN,
      "dynamicField2" TEXT,
      "dynamicField3" TEXT INDEX USING FULLTEXT,
      "dynamicField4" TEXT
   )  NOT NULL,
  "createdAt" TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
  "updatedAt" TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY ("field1", "field2")
)
...
...
...
```

I've taken a snapshot and now I'm trying to restore/upgrade to a higher version, which is facing with above-mentioned error.

Update 1:

```
SELECT DISTINCT version['created'], version['upgraded'] FROM "information_schema"."tables" WHERE table_schema not IN ('sys','information_schema','pg_catalog') limit 100;

Result from query:
version['created']  version['upgraded']
4.0.12              4.2.7 
4.1.5               4.2.7 
4.2.7               NULL
```

```
SELECT distinct min_lucene_version FROM sys.shards limit 100;

Result from query:

min_lucene_version
8.0.0 
8.5.1 
8.4.0
```

Comment: Just to be sure ... You 1) Create a snapshot on a 4.2.7 cluster, 2) then start a new cluster with 4.3.4 and 3) restore the snapshot from the 4.2.7 cluster?

Comment: @proddata Yes, that's correct. If there is any other alternative is there please do let me know.

PS: I'm running crate on docker

Comment: Was that snapshot repository created with an earlier (pre 4.0) version? I can't really replicate this. (Just tried with that exact schema) Also it seems like 4.2.7 had a bug, that would it make impossible to dynamically add a fulltext indexed column after table creation, which also doesn't help.

Comment: Could you run 
```sql
SELECT DISTINCT version['created'], version['upgraded']
FROM "information_schema"."tables"
WHERE table_schema not IN ('sys','information_schema','pg_catalog')
```
and
```sql
SELECT distinct min_lucene_version FROM sys.shards
```
on the non-upgraded cluster?

Comment: I've updated the question with output, Please refer there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The above mentioned error

> [fields : {keyword={type=keyword, ignore_above=256}}]

hints, that you would want to upgrade/restore a table  / snapshot created with a CrateDB version <3.0 to CrateDB 4.x

CrateDB 4.x only supports tables created with 3.x and up
CrateDB 3.x only supported tables created with 2.x and up

A snapshot is basically just a copy of the Lucene indexes/segments

As mentioned in the comment, you should run the following queries to check, which version the tables were created with:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT version['created'], version['upgraded'] FROM "information_schema"."tables" WHERE table_schema not IN ('sys','information_schema','pg_catalog')
```

```sql
SELECT distinct min_lucene_version FROM sys.shards
```

---

If only older tables are affected I would suggest to reindex those tables using 4.2.7 and then run the upgrade

```sql
SHOW CREATE table old;
INSERT INTO new SELECT * FROM old;
--or
COPY old TO;
COPY new FROM;
```

Comment: I've updated the question with output, Please refer. I'm not sure why it was not saved previously. 

Anyways, query output says tables were created in 4.x onwards and upgraded to 4.2.7

Comment: I tried to replicate this with the upgrade path, but can't. Which leads me to think that there is still some information missing. Which version was the affected table created with?

Comment: I would suggest to recreated the tables within 4.2.7 (using the full schema of `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and an `INSERT INTO x SELECT * FROM y` statement or `COPY TO / FROM`

Comment: The affected table was created in 4.0.12. Also on your suggestion create a table again is difficult in terms of process, because we've to migrate the whole database which has 100s of tables.

Comment: Let me give it a try with REINDEXing as all tables won't have issues(figure crossed)